# Convert char columns to nvarchar, in order to change the codepage (language encoding) for data already in the table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that was imported from another source as a column with the char datatype, but the field has international characters. I would like to use nvarcvhar in my table. How can I achieve this?

I already tried updating the columns (using an alter table statement, or "cast as") but the info stored did not get converted.

Thanks

Comment: Please add scale specifics like # of tables, # of constraints (on affected columns), naming conventions observed with indexes/constraints and your ability to change all that by a dynamic SQL script.  Unless the existing answers did answer you already.

Comment: Re edit, if you have corrupt data, please specify how it got corrupt, for example what code page the data should be in and what it seems to be in instead if you know that.

Comment: I need to convert from codepage 1252  to codepage gb2312 (chinese)

Comment: That makes it much harder, it might be best to throw away the database and follow the answer when reinserting the data if you still have the original source.  The data basically got corrupt in this 8 bit codepage.

Comment: I highly doubt that because when I run a crystal report against this table it shows the proper chinese characters

Comment: Now we got somewhere.  See my answer.  BTW gb2312 is not a designation of a codepage and your data is in no way in code page 1252.  If it was in 1252, it would have been lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is currently in EUC-CN, masquerading as CP1252.  It is not lost.

You have [several approaches](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/unicode-migration/#sql) available for conversion to Unicode (look at Converting SQL databases section for overview).  In case of SQL Server, you can [create extended stored procedures](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/values/article.php/c4571/Converting-from-Code-Page-to-Unicode.htm) for conversion from EUC-CN to Unicode.  This will work but it is not exactly easy (in this case use code page 51936 for your data).

With some luck, depending on what particular characters occur in your data, and what language packs you have installed, you might be able to convert as if from code page 936 like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabasename COLLATE Chinese_PRC
```

If this succeeds, do the same for every column you are going to convert:

```
ALTER TABLE mytablename ALTER COLUMN mycolumnname
        varchar(4000) COLLATE Chinese_PRC NOT NULL
```

And only then convert them to NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 4):

like this

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName NVARCHAR(size)
```

example

```
CREATE TABLE test (bla VARCHAR(50))
GO
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN bla NVARCHAR(50)
```

Make sure that you prefix the string with N when doing the insert

```
INSERT test VALUES (N'漢語')

SELECT * FROM test
```

output

```
bla
--------------------------------------------------
漢語

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Whatever you do, don't use the SSMS designer/wizard, it will recreate the whole table, see here for example [When changing column data types use ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER Column syntax, don't drop and recreate column](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/when-changing-column-data-types)

Comment: I already tried this but the data that is stored is still the same. Ex: (ÔÝÍ£)°²»Õ»ªÈÊÉúÎï¼¼ÊõÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾

Comment: see additional text I added, you need to prefix with N, so N'漢語' instead of '漢語'

Comment: You need to reload the data since it is stored in a different format, 1 byte vs 2 bytes (unicode)

Comment: That is impossible because it is getting this info from an erp system.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the corrupt data? A sql script vs?

Comment: @hagi If it's corrupt, how do you think SQL is going to magically de-corrupt it?  You need to get the source again to get correct data, there is no magic bullet for garbage data like this.

Comment: I am not sure.. by using ascii and unicode functions and reading two bytes at a time somwhow?

Comment: The data is LOST.  You wrote 2 bytes to a single byte, essentially.  That extra byte of data has been discarded and is lost forever.  There is no going back without getting the original data again.

Comment: I highly doubt that because when I run a crystal report against this table it shows the proper chinese characters.

Comment: Then your data is fine, copy the output from your table and paste into MS Word, it should show you Chinese characters,,,you only need to encode it from the front end

Comment: @SQLMenace, yes it looks fine but this requires manual work. our users will create new customers in the erp system and someone needs to do this.  How do crystal and excel convert these values?  Is there a way to do such thing in sql?

Comment: I am saying the data is correct, sql doesn't need to do anything, your presentation layer has to do this

Comment: thanks @SQLMenace, the only thing that is not working is our SSAS cube. it does not convert this to regular chinese characters. any ideas?

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table your_table alter column your_column nvarchar(length)
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efb3c/1)

Comment: Already tried that.  The data I stored in the table is the same.  Char Column :(ÔÝÍ£)°²»Õ»ªÈÊÉúÎï¼¼ÊõÓÐÏÞ¹«Ë¾