# REPLACE CHAR(0) NVARCHAR Latin1_General_CI_AS collation

Tags: sql-server, replace

In SQL Server I am trying to replace `CHAR(0)` with `''` but it is not working  as my field is actually a `NVARCHAR` field, my collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS` but when I convert to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` it only works for `VARCHAR` and not `NVARCHAR`.

```
SELECT val, REPLACE(val , CHAR(0), 'x')
FROM    (
         SELECT 'a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS val
        ) AS X
```

Returns `a | a`

```
SELECT val, REPLACE(CAST(val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS varchar(100)), CHAR(0), 'x')
FROM    (
         SELECT 'a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS val
        ) AS X
```

Returns `a | axb`

```
SELECT val, REPLACE(CAST(val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS varchar(100)), CHAR(0), 'x')
FROM    (
         SELECT CAST('a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS val
        ) AS X
SELECT val, REPLACE(CAST(val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS nvarchar(100)), CHAR(0), 'x')
```

Returns `a | axb`

```
FROM    (
         SELECT CAST('a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS val
        ) AS X
SELECT val, REPLACE(CAST(val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS varchar(100)), nCHAR(0), 'x')
```

Returns `a | a`

```
FROM    (
         SELECT CAST('a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS val
        ) AS X
SELECT val, REPLACE(CAST(val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS nvarchar(100)), nCHAR(0), 'x')
```

Returns `a | a`

```
FROM    (
         SELECT CAST('a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS val
        ) AS X
```

Returns `a | a`

Is there a way that I can replace the `0x0000` characters with `''` and not lose my NVARCHAR state

Edit: the expected value is `a | axb` for the last query (or one that is similar but will support `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: perhaps this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451684/convert-char-columns-to-nvarchar-in-order-to-change-the-codepage-language-enco) could be some help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a binary collate clause and there is no need to `CAST`

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT CAST('a' + CHAR(0) + 'b' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS val)
SELECT val,
       REPLACE(val COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN, nCHAR(0), 'x')
FROM   T
```